# PoolConnection JDBC Best Practice

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, pool

im implementig always a Pool Class for my connection and a try{}catch{}finally sentence.

This is the pool:

```
package Util;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Vector;


public class PoolvTiger
{
    private Vector <Connection> connections = new Vector<Connection>();
    protected String jdbc;
    protected String servidor;
    protected String usuario;
    protected String password;
    protected int cantCon;
    private static PoolvTiger pool;
    private PoolvTiger()
    {
        getConfiguration();


        for (int i= 0; i< cantCon;i++)
            connections.add(connect());
    }


    public static PoolvTiger getPoolConnection()
    {
        if (pool== null)
            pool =new PoolvTiger();
        return pool;
    }
    private Connection connect()
    {
        try
        {
            //Setear driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            String dbConnectString = jdbc + servidor; 
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection (dbConnectString, usuario, password);

            return con;
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Mensaje Error: " + e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Stack Trace: " + e.getStackTrace());
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Mensaje Error: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Stack Trace: " + ex.getStackTrace());
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void getConfiguration()
    {

        // Carga del fichero de propiedades 
        try 
        {

           //Leo los valores de configuracion
           jdbc = "jdbc:mysql://";
           cantCon = 20;

           servidor = Props.vtiger_host+":3306/"+Props.vtiger_db;
           usuario =Props.vtiger_user;
           password = Props.vtiger_pass;



         } 
        catch (Exception e) 
         {
                System.out.println("Mensaje Error: " + e.getMessage());
                System.out.println("Stack Trace: " + e.getStackTrace());
         }
    }
    public void closeConnections()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<connections.size();i++)
        {
            try
            {
                connections.elementAt(i).close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Mensaje Error: " + e.getMessage());
                System.out.println("Stack Trace: " + e.getStackTrace());
            }
        }
    }
    public  Connection getConnection()
    {
        Connection c = null;
        if (connections.size()>0)
            c = connections.remove(0);
        else
        {
            c = connect();
            //System.out.println("EXITO");
        }
        return c;
    }
    public void realeaseConnection(Connection c)
    {
        connections.add(c);
    }
}
```

And this is my usuall implementation, for UPDATES, INSERTS , AND SELECTS:

```
Connection conn=null;
        try{
              conn=PoolvTiger.getPoolConnection().getConnection();
              PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM something");
              ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
              PoolvTiger.getPoolConnection().realeaseConnection(conn);

         }catch(Exception e){
             Log.log("ERROR al validar usuario");
         }finally {
             PoolvTiger.getPoolConnection().realeaseConnection(conn);
         }
```

Im doing it wright?

I noticed i dont use the closeConnections() method of the Pool, also i dont close anything, but my app works just fine...

Do the resultsets and statements have to be closed as well?

To add, im using a LOT of methods with this format. Its not just one, they are many, so im looking for the PERFECT implementation.

thanks!

Comment: If you're looking for the perfect implementation, why did you make your own instead of getting one of the tried and tested connection pools?

Comment: I didnt make it my own,they provide me with this pool in college. And i used it all year in class

Comment: Do you have a link with the perfect implementation to show me?

Comment: How can you be sure there is a *perfect* implementation?